How make a rigidbody not to change its trajectory by any external collsion?
I am trying to make a platformer game in which the player is able to run on the platforms. I have the platforms moving from the right to the left direction and the player is standing on top of the platforms.
When a is pressed I addForce the the player's rigidbody component till a certain point and the the force stays clamped. The problem that I currently face is that I the when the player move in  a certain direction it also cause the platforms to move in that direction too and setting the isKinematic on the platforms to true make the static and not move completely.
I am a beginner so I really would appreciate an amount of suggestion.
platform.cs:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlatformLogic : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public new Rigidbody rigidbody;
    public float forceFactor;

    public BoxCollider primaryBoxCollider;//The box collider on which the player will stand on
    public CapsuleCollider secondryBoxCollider;//The box collider on which the player will climb onto
    void Start()
    {
        this.rigidbody = this.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        this.primaryBoxCollider = this.gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider>();
        this.secondryBoxCollider = this.gameObject.GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>();
        this.rigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.left * forceFactor,ForceMode.Impulse);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {            
    }
}

player.cs:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;

public class playerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public BoxCollider primaryCollider;//This is for  walking, damage etc.
    public SphereCollider secondryCollider;//This is for climbing only
    
    public new Rigidbody rigidbody;
    void Start()
    {
        primaryCollider = this.gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider>();
        secondryCollider = this.gameObject.GetComponent<SphereCollider>();
        rigidbody = this.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            this.rigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.left,ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
        else if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            this.rigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.right,ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
    }
}


The physics system will complicate all movement. Neither the player nor the platform need physics.

@agone The built-in physics engine is perfectly appropriate for some platformers. Since the OP is a beginner, it's probably better for them to start with the built-in systems instead of having to write their own systems for collision detection, depenetration, momentum, etc.

@Divyansh_undley Are the platforms children of the player? Or, did you accidentally add the playerScript component to the platforms or their parent?

The platforms are not children of the player nor did I add playerScript to the platforms or their parents.

Can @agone give me some resources to do that?

The platforms should be kinematic to achieve what you want (unless the platforms are supposed to be affected by other bodies in the scene; alternative dynamic rigidbody solution at the end.) The reason they're not moving anymore after you set isKinematic to true is because Rigidbody.AddForce does not apply forces on kinematic bodies (it's mentioned in both of the docs I linked). You can read more about the kinematic body type in the docs here (it's the 2D docs but it applies to 3D.) To quote it:

To reposition a Kinematic Rigidbody 2D, it must be repositioned
explicitly via Rigidbody2D.MovePosition or Rigidbody2D.MoveRotation.
Use physics queries to detect collisions, and scripts to decide where
and how the Rigidbody 2D should move.

So, instead of applying a force to a kinematic body, you call MovePosition on it with the new position. Note that MovePosition takes in the new position, not a movement delta.
Since you were applying an impulse in Start instead of a constant force every frame, that's not gonna work with MovePosition, so you have to convert that impulse force logic into something that works in Update.
OR... You can always just increase the mass of the platform's rigidbody to make sure the player cannot affect them too much. That way you don't have to make the platforms kinematic. You might have to increase the impulse force accordingly though. And I'm guessing the platforms will still not be exactly at the spot you want them to, but it might be fine in your case.
